# Quick Links Only Reporting Click Data?

Tags: branch.io

It's been a while since I have used branch. Can you still create quick links and pass revenue data with them using quick links using key value pairs?

I used this link (https://funnynotfunny.app.link/e/WLFHDadHat) to see if key value pairs can pass just add to cart and revenue. I use to do this all the time but it's been a few years. Thank you.